# While checking the get and post API in postman is only recieving the object id rather than the JSON file

Tags: angular, mongodb, express, postman

This is the JSON file. It's a demo one

```
[
{
    "name":"job"
     "email":"ron23@gmail.com",
     
}
 ]
the output am receiving is this
[
    {
        "_id": "613c40b5e594ed0b74a2b09b",
        "__v": 0
    },
]
```

This what the postman is returning.
Can someone please provide it a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, if you looking for something in database, you can do that in the following manner. I shared a function of find friends in my database

```
let result = await UserHelper.findFriend(req.body.friendUserName,req.body.yourUserName);



let response = ResponseHelper.setResponse(ResponseCode.SUCCESS, Message.REQUEST_SUCCESSFUL, result);
    return res.status(response.code).json(response);
```

//UserHelper.js

```
exports.findFriend = async (userName, user) => {
        return await User.findOne({_id: user._id}, {friends: {$elemMatch: {userName: userName}}});
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

this is inserted id  (`_id`) of data that stored in collection of mongodb